# How to Get Data from Laravel Controller and Compare It?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

In my Controller, I have the following.

```php
public function check_login(Request $request)
{
    $users = User::all('user_type');
    if ($users === 'teacher') {
        echo 'teacher';
    } else if ($users === 'student') {
        echo 'student';
    } else {
        echo 'nothing';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the `if` and `else if` are not working.

Comment: Could you explain what you would like to happen and what is actually happening instead? In what context are you calling it? It'd help if you provided an example of how it's being called along with which condition you want it to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the method `All()` you're getting the whole collection. 
Try loop the `$users` like this:

```
$users = User::all();
foreach($users as $user)
{
    if($user->user_type == 'teacher')
    {
        echo 'teacher';
    }
    else if($user->user_type == 'student'){
        echo 'student';
    }

    else{
        echo 'nothing';
    }
}
```

Here you're comparing each object from the User Collection

Comment: it runs two times else 'nothing'

Comment: use this: ``` $users = User::all() ```

Comment: Worked? make sure that your users table have values.

Comment: yes i have two values one have type student and 1 have type teacher

Comment: Glad i could help. please accept this answer (check button) so we can close this question